# Quadrature signal generation with bit manipulation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, stm32

I try to generate quadrature signal but with the lowest operation possible. I use a STM32 and GPIO pin B8 and B9 for sending the signal.
couple of pin 8 and 9 have four possible options which are in clock wise:
0/0 1/0 1/1 and 0/1
and counter clockwise 
0/0 0/1 1/1 1/0
I can't find the way with bitwise to be able to quickly set or reset the bit for the selected pin.
Moreover, I must be able to go clock or counterclokwise and change sense whenever I want like if it was a rotary or linear encoder.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Increment/decrement (modulo 4) ?

Comment: that won't produce the required 0,1,3,2 sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bit-banging**

Bitwise thinking, B9 gets the previous value of B8, and B8 gets the inverse of B9, or the other way round when counting down. You swap the two bits, and exclusive-or with `0x100` or `0x200` depending on the direction.

```
inline void incB89(int down) {
    uint32_t temp;

    /* read the current output state */
    temp = GPIOB->ODR;

    /* modifying the significant bit-pair
       don't care about overflow */
    temp = (((temp & 0x100) << 1) | ((temp & 0x200) >> 1)) ^ (0x100 << down);

    /* Setting the reset bits BR8 and BR9. This has the effect that
       bits 8 and 9 will be copied into the ODR, and the rest will
       be left alone */
    temp |= ((1 << 24) | (1 << 25));

    GPIOB->BSRR = temp;
}
```

**Using a timer** (or two)

On most STM32 series controllers, `TIM4` channels 3 and 4 outputs can be mapped to PB8 and PB9. If you have one of these, this timer can control the outputs autonomously, unaffected by code, memory, or interrupt latency.

- Set the GPIO mode and alternate function registers according to the reference manual of your controller.
- Configure both channel 3 and 4 to toggle mode, set the `OC1M` and `OC2M` bits in `TIM4->CCMR1` to `0b011`.
- Set the input clock, prescaler `PSC` and reload `ARR` to achieve twice the desired frequency, because each output will be toggled once in every timer cycle.
- Set `TIM4->CCR3=0` and `TIM4->CCR4=(TIM4->ARR+1)/2` for counting in one direction. Swap them (while the counter is stopped) to reverse direction.
- Enable the outputs in `TIM4->CCER`.
- You can start and stop counting by setting or resetting the `CEN` bit of `TIM4->CR1`.
- To count the cycles, you can to configure an interrupt for toggle or update events in `TIM4->DIER`, or use another timer as a slave to TIM4.

To use e.g. `TIM3` to count:

- Set the `MMS` bits in `TIM4->CR2` to `0b010` to output a trigger pulse on each overflow.
- Configure `TIM3->SMCR` to External Clock Mode 1, and select the internal trigger of TIM4.
- Set `TIM3->ARR` to the required number of half-cycles - 1.
- Configure an interrupt on update.
- Start the counter.

There are some more tricks possible with timers, like using DMA bursts triggered by the slave to update the `ARR` and `CCR` registers of the master timer from a table of "wawelength" values.

Comment: Hi berendi, thank you for your help.
I would like to understand the use of variable down ? what i'm supposed to use?

I was using timer for reading quadrature encoder. your setup seems to be very detailed, i will study it closely..

Comment: `down` reverses direction. When `down==0`, the bit shift does nothing, bit 8 gets reversed after swapping. When `down==1`, the mask will be shifted, and bit 9 will be reversed.

Comment: OK thanks a lot.
Would you mind to post the main.c with the timer set as described?
I tried something but I don't understand all parameters so I don't get the desired square wave.
That would be very kind ;)

Comment: @vib: You could post _your_ code in a separate question, describing where you've been stuck now, what do you want and what did you get instead. That's how this site is supposed to work. Don't forget adding a few words about your hardware, part number, clock setup including APB frequency at the very least. A timer setup that works on my STM32L1 clocked with 16 MHz might be useless for you.

Comment: Here is the pastebin of my code:
https://pastebin.com/GhJXbnR4
I focused on setting up the timer first.
If I understand well I should add the following instructions in static void MX_TIM4_Init(void):

 TIM4->CCR3=0;
 TIM4->CCR4=(TIM4->ARR+1)/2;
 TIM4->CCER;
 TIM4->CCMR1 = 0x3; //instead of 0b011 as binary not accepted but how to specify OC1M and OC2M?

I will go step by step, first this question and then following once this one is resolved
Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Well... I mean ask a new question on Stackoverflow. That way, someone else can answer it even if I can't figure it out.